# Meteor aldeed:autoform custom arrayField template not working

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform, simple-schema

I've looked for tutorials about AutoForm's custom field templates but I'm not sure where I'm going wrong with mine. If anyone has any suggestions it would be greatly appreciated.

My Schema: One field is an Array of Objects.

```
guests: {
    type: Array,
    minCount: 1,
    maxCount: 10,
    label: "Guests in Party"
},
"guests.$": {
    type: Object,
    label: "Guest Object"
},
"guests.$.firstName": {
    type: String,
    label: "First Name"
},
"guests.$.lastName": {
    type: String,
    label: "Last Name"
}
```

Template Code:

```
<template name='afArrayField_guestsObjectField'>
    {{#afEachArrayItem name="guests" minCount="this.atts.minCount" maxCount="this.atts.maxCount"}}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Guest</label>
        {{> afObjectField name="this.name" label="false" template='customObjectField'}}
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            {{#if afArrayFieldHasLessThanMaximum name="guests"}}
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary autoform-add-item" data-autoform-field="{{guests}}" data-autoform-minCount="{{this.atts.minCount}}" data-autoform-maxCount="{{this.atts.maxCount}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button>
            {{/if}}
            {{#if afArrayFieldHasMoreThanMinimum name="guests"}}
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary autoform-remove-item pull-left"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></button>
        {{/if}}
        </div>
    </div>
    {{/afEachArrayItem}}
</template>

<template name="afObjectField_customObjectField">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        {{> afFieldInput name="this.firstName" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name"}}

        {{#if afFieldIsInvalid name='this.firstName'}}
            <span class="help-block">{{{afFieldMessage name='this.firstName'}}}</span>
        {{/if}}
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        {{> afFieldInput name="this.lastName" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name"}}

        {{#if afFieldIsInvalid name='this.lastName'}}
            <span class="help-block">{{{afFieldMessage name='this.lastName'}}}</span>
        {{/if}}
    </div>
</template>
```

The problem I am having is that the plus buttons shows up after the firstName and lastName field how I want it to, but when I press it another guest object (in the form) does not generate. Any thoughts?